Django REST Framework. вложенный сериализатор игнорирует мои данные
Через fetch передаю данные с одним файлом + заголовок + описание + еще один json (answers_set), которые необходимо так же сериализовать. Запрос получается следующий:
<QueryDict: {'title': ['dsasad'], 'description': ['dsadads'], 'content': ['<p>dsadas</p>'], 'answers_set': ['[{"title":"asddas"},{"title":"dsaasd"}]'], 'tags': ['dsasda'], 'blog': ['11'], 'preview': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: Django-авторизация.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>

То есть, данные есть в answers_set, ничего не пропадает,
сама вьюшка c классом:
class SurveyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Survey.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SurveySerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    # parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser, JSONParser]

def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.action in ["add_view", "hide_survey", "show_survey"]:
        return SurveyNoneSerializer
    elif self.action == "send_scores_to_option":
        return SurveyScoresSerializer
    else:
        return SurveySerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    if self.action == 'send_scores_to_option':
        return SurveyRadio.objects.all()
    return super().get_queryset()

def custom_get_object(self, **params):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field

    assert lookup_url_kwarg in self.kwargs, (
        (self.__class__.__name__, lookup_url_kwarg)
    )

    filter_kwargs = {self.lookup_field: self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]}
    obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs, **params)

    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)

    return obj

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    _ = get_object_or_404(Blog, user=request.user.id, id=request.data.get("blog", False))

    data = {}

    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_published_post:
        # _data = QueryDict.copy(request.data)

        _data = request.data
        print(_data)
        _data["language"] = request.user.language

        draft = DraftSurvey.objects.filter(
            user=request.user.id, blog=_data["blog"]
        )
        if not _data.get("preview", False):
            if draft and draft[0].preview:
                _data["preview"] = draft[0].preview

        serializer = SurveySerializer(data=_data, user=request.user)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            survey = serializer.save()

            if draft:
                draft[0].delete()

            data["success"] = "Successful created a new survey."
            data["slug"] = survey.slug
        else:
            data = serializer.errors
    else:
        data["ban"] = "You can't publish surveys."

    print(data)

    return Response(data)

Сериализаторы:
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = SurveyRadio
        fields = [
            "id",
            "title",
        ]


class SurveySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.CharField(required=False, write_only=True)
    answers_set = AnswerSerializer(source="answers", many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = [
            "preview",
            "title",
            "description",
            "content",
            "language",
            "tags",
            "blog",
            "answers_set",
            "level_access",
        ]

На выходе же я получаю следующую ошибку :
{'answers_set': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}


Кажется дело в том, что answers_set это не json. ТО есть не список объектов answers, а строка, содержащаяя json со списком объектов.
Вы можете исправить это внутри fetch'a. (Т.к. вы не предоставили его код, я не знаю, как его изменить)
С другой стороны вы можете попробовать делать это в вашем view:
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    _ = get_object_or_404(Blog, user=request.user.id, id=request.data.get("blog", False))

    data = {}

    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_published_post:
        _data = request.data.copy()
        print(_data)
        _data["language"] = request.user.language

        draft = DraftSurvey.objects.filter(
            user=request.user.id, blog=_data["blog"]
        )
        if not _data.get("preview", False):
            if draft and draft[0].preview:
                _data["preview"] = draft[0].preview

        # Пытаемся преобразовать из строки в list.
        try:
            _data["answers_set"] = json.loads(_data["answers_set"])

        except json.JSONDecodeError: 
            raise ValidationError([
                ValidationError("answers_set", code="Invalid JSON format.")
            ]) # django 3.0+ 

        serializer = SurveySerializer(data=_data, user=request.user)
        ... # Остальной код

С другой стороны проблема может заключаться в том, что вы указываете как источник поле answers, а передаете answers_set:
class SurveySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.CharField(required=False, write_only=True)
    answers_set = AnswerSerializer(source="answers", many=True) # Вот здесь.


если не указывать заголовок multipart/form-data, а просто передать json, то все работает, но мне нужно отправлять данные с фотографией.

тогда разве мой способ с сериализацией во view вам не подходит?

Я нашел решение, я уже пробовал так делать, но проблема была вот в чем, сериализатор игнорирует эти данные в списке с json, если тип request.data это QueryDict, я собственно преобразовал этот QueryDict в обычный словарик, использовал для внутреннего json json.loads, и все заработало, все answers проходят сериализацию внутри сериализатора другого
